# Am I doing this right? Nuget Package Restore with centralized packages folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

I placed a **nuget.config** file in my project root folder that specifies where all NuGet packages should go for all my solutions.

Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="D:\Projects\Development\NuGet Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

I have also enabled **NuGet Package Restore** on all my solutions.

When I first set this up, the nuget.config file was being ignored--all NuGet packages were being placed in a "packages" folder in the solution folder. I tried deleting this folder numerous times, but invariably, NuGet would recreate it and fill it with packages.

After much trial and error, I stumbled upon the `<PackagesDir>` element in "NuGet.targets" and noticed that commenting it out finally allowed the packages to be placed in the correct folder in my project root.

Here's the relevant line from NuGet.targets

```
<PackagesDir>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SolutionDir), "packages"))</PackagesDir>
```

My question is simply whether commenting out the `PackagesDir` element in the NuGet.targets file is the intended method to get my nuget.config file to be followed or if I'm missing a more obvious solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things in play in your question:

- Where does NuGet store packages?
- NuGet package restore for the open project(s) / solution

Regarding the first: setting the *repositoryPath* key in your nuget.config file is the correct approach to instruct NuGet to extract packages in a different folder from the default. This setting is used whenever a developer adds a package refernce to your project.

For NuGet package restore, thissetting is overridden by the setting you found in *NuGet.targets*. This setting is used when restoring packages upon build of a solution.

If you want to use package restore *and* a custom path, you indeed have to specify both. The first one for your devs, the second one for package restore.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance. I will keep doing as I am.

Comment: Gah!!! I just wasted so much time trying to sort that out... Why would NuGet want to have you configure that value twice? I really wish the 2.1 release notes would have pointed that out...